# Which edition of Dialogflow (ES and/or CX) does CCAI work with?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx, contact-center

If I start implementing my agents using ES, will I be able to "integrate" them with CCAI (when I get to that stage)? Or does CCAI only work with agents implemented on CX?

Answer (score 1):

Hey man you can use both ES and CX with CCAI to create CCAI sessions -
This is a nice course from Google that explains those relationships between Google products -> https://www.coursera.org/learn/contact-center-ai-conversational-design-fundamentals/home/welcome

Also you can check the Voximplant connector for Dialogflow ES, CX and Full CCAI support for Cloud Telephony -> https://voximplant.com/blog/dialogflow_one_click_Integration

[image]

Check the tutorial I made for the CX ES connector in our No code tool -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kp5haQ7zNQ